# how to call different jquery actions in responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm at the point to convert my project into an responsive design.

What is the most handy and universal solution do you suggest to implement different jQuery-blocks for each breakpoint?

I want to keep all scripts in one file cause of number of http-requests.

That's what I've found:

- [breakpoint.js](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/) -> define all breakpoints doubled in CSS & JS
- http://responsejs.com/ -> define breakpoints in body data-attr
- [OnMediaQuery](http://www.springload.co.nz/love-the-web/responsive-javascript/) -> define human-readable names for the breakpoints (IMHO better, cause you're not bound to pixels)

My problem is, they all define callbacks, but I don't know how to bind or cancel any jQuery event-listeners in these cases.

e.g. I have:

```
$('#selector').click( function() {
    alert('selector clicked');
});
```

but that should only happen if in max-width of 320px.
In screen-sizes above that the click should return false or perform any other action

at the moment, I don't have a clue how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just create your own breakpoints in JS. Something like this. Adjust to your needs.

```
var isBreakPoint = function (bp) {
    var bps = [320, 480, 768, 1024],
        w = $(window).width(),
        min, max
    for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (bps[i] === bp) {
        min = bps[i-1] || 0
        max = bps[i]
        break
      }
    }
    return w > min && w <= max
}

// Usage
if (isBreakPoint(480)) { ... } // Breakpoint between 320 and 480
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$('#selector').click(function() {
    if (parseInt($(window).width()) < 320) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting modern browsers (IE10 upwards, and not IE mobile), then you should use the new `window.matchMedia()` method, as discrepancies between all the various browsers as to how they measure scrollbar width means that if you use for example `window.width()`, there will be a small range of pixels where the CSS behaves differently to the JS (I found this out the hard way).

This article goes in to further details: https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries

Use something like the following so that your JS and CSS work on exactly the same breakpoints:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide, write code specific for that */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide, write code specific for that */
}
```

The Mozilla Developer Network has documented this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 1):

I messed around with some libraries and stuff and ended up using this kind of responsive listener. It uses CSS media queries for breakpoints and UnderscoreJS for a throttler. The advantage I see is that the breakpoints are all defined in CSS instead of fragmented around various scripts.

Example CSS `@media` breakpoints using `:after` on the `body`:

```
body:after {
    content: 'widescreen';
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    body:after {
        content: "extra-large";
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body:after {
        content: "large";
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    body:after {
        content: "medium";
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    body:after {
        content: "small";
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    body:after {
        content: "tiny";
    }
}
```

Example listener script waiting to fire based on content of `body:after`. As you can see it's defined as 2 ranges in this example for show/hide/move/create widgets based on device generality:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function(e){
    var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').content.replace(/"|'/g, ''),
        mobile = ["tiny", "small", "medium", "large"].indexOf(size),
        desktop = ["extra-large", "widescreen"].indexOf(size);

    $('.placehold').html('computed breakpoint: ' + size + '<br />mobile index = ' + mobile + '<br />desktop index = ' + desktop);

    if (mobile != -1) {
        $('.placehold2').html('mobile range');
    } else if (desktop != -1) {
        $('.placehold2').html('desktop range');
    }
}, 100)).trigger('resize');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dhaupin/nw7qbdzx/ - Just resize the output pane in jsfiddle to test it out.

**EDIT:** Apparently browsers render the :after contents via `window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').content` differently and insert either single or double quotes. Added a replace to scrub them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 you can use this jQuery plugin to check what breakpoint is set by checking the CSS display property of elements.

https://jacoblett.github.io/IfBreakpoint/

Then use it like

```
if ( xs == true ) { 
  alert("mobile first");
}

// Update on window resize
$( window ).resize( function(){
  $("h2").text( breakpoint ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution:

```js
// Example for your Request
var clickCounter = 0;

$('#selector').click( function() {
    if (ifMaxWidth(320)) {
        console.log('selector clicked #'+ clickCounter++ +" times");
    }
});

// More examples
bpChecks();
$(window).on("orientationchange resize", function(event) { bpChecks(); });

function bpChecks()
{
    ifMinWidth(992, function() {
        console.log("hello from callback 1");
    });
    
    ifMaxWidth(1199, function() {
        console.log("hello from callback 2");
    });
    
    ifBetweenMinAndMaxWidth(992, 1199, function() {
        console.log("hello from callback 3");
    });
}


// Methods
function ifBetweenMinAndMaxWidth(minWidth, maxWidth, callback)
{
    var w = $(window).width();

    var result = w < maxWidth && w > minWidth;
    if (result) {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is between "+ minWidth + " and " + maxWidth);
        if (callback !== undefined) { callback(); }
    } else {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is NOT between "+ minWidth + " and " + maxWidth);
    }
    return result;
}

function ifMinWidth(minWidth, callback)
{
    var w = $(window).width();

    var result = w > minWidth;
    if (result) {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is greater than "+ minWidth);
        if (callback !== undefined) { callback(); }
    } else {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is NOT greater than "+ minWidth);
    }
    return result;
};

function ifMaxWidth(maxWidth, callback)
{
    var w = $(window).width();

    var result = w < maxWidth;
    if (result) {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is smaller than "+ maxWidth);
        if (callback !== undefined) { callback(); }
    } else {
        console.log("width ("+ w +") is NOT smaller than "+ maxWidth);
    }
    return result;
};
```

```css
#selector { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-content: center;
  background: blue; 
  width: 250px; 
  height: 250px; 
}
#selector:hover { cursor:pointer; }
#selector p { color: white; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selector">
    <p>Click me</p>
</div>
```