# Responsive carousel only on mobile

Tags: responsive-design

In my design I want to have a carousel of 2 or more images for mobile device that transforms into a grid for desktop devices. Do you know some related resource?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? The more specific your question, the more likely that you'll get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

use various breakpoints as defined in Javascript: 
[how to call different jquery actions in responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387391/how-to-call-different-jquery-actions-in-responsive-design)

then in your narrow mobile breakpoint, you see the carousel to launch . Then you could remove that carousel if they switch to the bigger breakpoint. And have that show a grid thats done with CSS.