# Slick.js - Responsive breakpoint custom function

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to launch an event when `Slick.js` breakpoint gets triggered.
The `init` event gets triggered even if the breakpoint is not hit.

Is there a way around it?

Here is my code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(".homepage_slider").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    arrows:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:3500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [                           
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            init: changeImages()
          }
        }
    ]
});

function changeImages(){
    $j('img.slider-image').each(function() {
        $j(this).attr('src', $j(this).attr('data-mobile'));
    });                     
}
```

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
$j('.homepage_slider').on('breakpoint', function(){
    console.log("test");
    $j('img.slider-image').each(function() {
        $j(this).attr('src', $j(this).attr('data-mobile'));
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

Found this post: [how to call different jquery actions in responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387391/)

```
var isBreakPoint = function (bp) {
    var bps = [320, 480, 768, 1024],
        w = $j(window).width(),
        min, max
    for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (bps[i] === bp) {
            min = bps[i-1] || 0
            max = bps[i]
            break
        }
    }
    return w > min && w <= max
}

if (isBreakPoint(480)) {
    $j('img.slider-image').each(function() {
        $j(this).attr('src', $j(this).attr('data-mobile'));
    });
}
```

This workaround works, but would be nice if I found one that works whenever `Slick.js` breakpoint event is hit so there is no discrepancy between two methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the «Events» section of the [Slick's documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/):

> In slick 1.4, callback methods have been deprecated and replaced with events.
> <...>
> **breakpoint**
> Arguments: event, slick, breakpoint.
> Fires after a breakpoint is hit.

So you need to take two steps:

1. Set breakpoints that you need, using the `responsive` option.
2. Catch the `breakpoint` event and do whatever you want.

For example:

```js
var $myCarousel = $('#myCarousel');

/* Step 1 */
$myCarousel.slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
  responsive: [
    { breakpoint: 500 },
    { breakpoint: 768 },
    { breakpoint: 992 }
  ]
});

/* Step 2 */
$myCarousel.on('breakpoint', function(event, slick, breakpoint) {
  console.log('breakpoint ' + breakpoint);
});
```

```css
/* Decorations */
.my-carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-carousel .slick-next {
  right: 15px;
}
.my-carousel .slick-prev {
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick-theme.css">

<div id="myCarousel" class="my-carousel">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.7.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const $slick = $(".health-slick .items");
const $slick_item = $(".health-slick .items .item");

// INIT
  slickInit();
  animateHoverItem();

// FUNCTIONS
  function animateHoverItem() {
    $slick_item.mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('animate');
    });
    $slick_item.mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animate');
    });
    console.log(0); // this will call 1 time and 1 time when breakpoint window change
  }

  function slickInit() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $slick.slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 767.98,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 575.98,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
            },
          }
        ],
      });

      $slick.on('breakpoint', function(e){
        animateHoverItem();
      });
      
    });
  }
```